# how to solve.. abstract class? generics?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, hashmap, abstract-class

In my current setup I have a centralized helper class like the following:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
 {
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     if(task == null) {
         return;
     }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    ResponseJson p = null;
    try {
        p = gson.fromJson(result, ResponseJson.class);
    } catch(JsonSyntaxException e) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_sync_completed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("", e.getMessage() + " got '" + result + "'");
    }
    Log.i("", p.toString());
    Log.i("", result);

    if(p.status.equals(ResultStatus.SUCCESS.toString())) {
        task.success(p.data);
    } else if (p.status.equals(ResultStatus.FAIL.toString())) {
        task.fail(p.data);
    } else if (p.status.equals(ResultStatus.ERROR.toString())) {
        task.error(p.message);
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
 }
```

the problem is i want to make the `ResponseJson` class to be dynamic and the `data` attribute to be unique (sometimes i need `ArrayList<Something>` other times `HashMap<String, String>`) works for converting my JSON result. can i achieve this using generics or some other means?

Comment: The first question is if you are accessing the `data` of your object in a way that you have to be able to require any abstract behavior such that you can factor this behavior into an abstract base class - for example, do you traverse the data like a `Collection`? If no, I wouldn't see any point in an abstract base class.

It may be helping if you add any use cases where you access `data` and show us which tasks you perform with it to help you more specifically.

Comment: onPostExecute is returned some JSON. the `task` variable you see up top is a class i implement on the fly to handle the data returned by the server (it deals with a data structure directly, no json). when the data being returned from the server was consistent, i had no issues. now that there is some variation between what is returned, i want to handle it all in one place (my service class). what i'm currently doing is parsing json in every activity and manually specifying the JSON class file gson feeds into in the activity. the end result is very verbose and not DRY at all.

Comment: note: the service class makes the http call, checks status codes and all that jazz, and loads the returned JSON into a class via gson and hands it off to the on the fly implemented `task` class.

Comment: Yes, but do you decide what to do with the JSON depending on the content? If yes, you may should create different objects of a class hierarchy out of different JSON and move the logic what to do with which JSON content to the concrete classes of the class hierarchy. But more specific examples (code-like) would help deciding whether this is feasible!

Comment: tim's solution ended up being not as elegant as i'd like, but _much_ less verbose. going to end up using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `Object` as type of `data`,

```
class ResponseJson {
    Object data;
}
```

Later you can get the results as `ArrayList` or `Hashmap` as follows;

```
if (responseJson.data instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) responseJson.data;
} else if(responseJson.data instanceof HashMap<?, ?>) {
    HashMap<String, String> hashmap = (HashMap<String, String>) responseJson.data;
}
```

Due to type erasure, the parameterised type cannot be known at runtime. But if you know the type you can do an unchecked cast.